# Meteor / React.js: save image file to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, file-upload

I created a project, which is here: https://github.com/dartem/upload_files, and it uploads a file and saves it using FilesCollection. However, it looks like that an actual file is getting saved only temporarily in /cdn/storage and once I restart Meteor or if I open an incognito window an actual file doesn't exist.

I specify the path directory, which is assets/app/uploads/Images, but an image doesn't get saved in that directory. How can I save an actual file in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your demo up, and it does save files to that directory.

It's not advisable to store files in .meteor/local - basically the files there are temporary - meteor will remove and replace them as it rebuilds the app. This explains why you can't find them again later.

It is also possible to write the files to the public directory, but that will trigger a rebuild of your app every time you save a file, which isn't a good side effect.

I would recommend that you only save the files to gridFS or AWS (or any of the other storage options). You *could* save them to a folder somewhere else in the file system, as long as you have a way of serving them up (some kind of web server like apache, express or whatever). Your choice based on what sysadmin capability you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to save them into my public/images/uploads file directory what would be the best way to accomplish that? I thought of FS from Node but I got into lots of errors right away. Any suggestions/examples? Basically, what I want is to upload/move files into a public directory so those files would physically exist there.

Comment: From the server you can use fs, no problems. In development, if you write to the /public directory it will force a rebuild every time, which won't help your development workflow, in fact the random timing of rebuild is a problem straight away. I think if you create a folder outside your meteor your project, lets say /Users/mikkel/myproj/uploads, and symlink it from your public directory, so it will be /public/uploads, then it might not do a rebuild, and you can maybe refer to the files from your app as /uploads/... You might be able to do a similar thing in production without fear of a rebuild

Comment: Thanks, Mikkel. I still have no idea how to make it work but I understood the general idea. Codewise, where can I look up code samples for Meteor/React combination? I already tried Meteor FS-Node-like packages but I couldn't figure out how to make them work for my app-demo. All of them say something like Npm.require, which was giving me errors right away.

Comment: I think fs is already available in any server method (I checked my code to see), So your javascript to handle the files has to live in the server folder. React isn't there, it's just pure js you'll be writing. so pretty much any nodejs/npm examples should work for you.

Comment: Thank you Mikkel, I'll try. Maybe it will work for me this time

Comment: Mikkel, do you think it is safe to save images to a collection directly using data:image jpg;base64 as a converted string? I added it in here: https://github.com/dartem/upload_files/blob/master/imports/components/PhotosUpload.jsx using FileReader() and readAsDataURL()